# Changing destination of already purchased Shinkansen ticket

Tags: trains, tickets, japan

Using the official Smart EX app, I have reserved and paid for tickets for a JR Tokaido Shinkansen train service from Osaka, getting off at a stop well before Tokyo.  There are five people on this single booking, I have the pickup QR code but have not collected the tickets yet.

However, one person in the group had a change of plans and needs to go all the way to Tokyo instead.  **Can I change their ticket, and if yes, how?**

One way out seems to be to issue all tickets as is from the ticket machine, and then line up at a ticket counter to change just the one to go to Tokyo using the [one free change](https://global.jr-central.co.jp/en/tickets/change/) policy, but I'm a little concerned about if we'll have time to do this and would prefer to make the amendment on board if possible.

Comment: Can't you just buy an extra ticket from "stop" to Tokyo ?

Comment: @Hilmar Yes, but the way Shinkansen pricing works, it would be considerably more expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few cases here:

- before your train's scheduled departure time, it's possible to change for *all* of the group via the app. It is also possible to cancel some passengers that are on the itinerary via the app;
- it is **impossible** to change the itinerary for only *part of the group* via the app. Instead, they instruct you to contact the service center, which probably means that you have to talk to them in Japanese (reference: [this page](https://expy.jp/faq/category/detail/?id=277#:%7E:text=%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82-,1%E5%90%8D%E5%88%86%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%88%E7%B4%84%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BF%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B,%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%80%82), [this page](https://smart-ex.jp/reservation/change/));
- it is of course possible to issue the tickets then refund them at a Midori no Madoguchi/ticket counter;
- if you don't board your train at the scheduled time/on the scheduled day (for nonreserved seats), you'll be automatically refunded next day, incurring the normal refund fee;
- it is not possible to change your itinerary while on board. It also possible to do a fare adjustment (*norikoshi*) on the train. However, according to official JR rules:

1. if your trip is <100km, or within a Large City Zone (which does not apply to Shinkansen), then you pay the difference of the price between A and B and between A and C;
2. otherwise, you pay for an extra undiscounted, full-fare ticket between B and C, which makes it very expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  Re: norikoshi, we paid the full undiscounted fare at the station anyway, so is there any disadvantage to doing it on board or on arrival?

Comment: Well, norikoshi is generally very expensive. You are effectively charged for the price of a separate (undiscounted) ticket from the said station to Tokyo, so it's not a good idea in general.

Comment: In general, JR norikoshi entails effectively purchasing a new ticket (except for short trips), so generally it's to be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, please clarify in your answer that you're basically buying an additional ticket, not just changing the old one.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, we ended up printing out the tickets we had already bought and taking my friend's ticket to the Shinkansen ticket counter at Shin-Osaka to change it.  The process was slightly involved:

- The previous ticket was cancelled and the credit card charge for it refunded (払い戻し *haraimodoshi*).
- A new ticket was issued and a new credit card charge made; this required presenting the previously used card and signing a receipt for the new charge

Note that my friend ended up switching to a different, faster train (Nozomi); it's possible this would have been a little more streamlined if they had not.  But the good news is that there was no handling fee (手数料 *tesuuryou*), so this didn't really cost anything other than the ~2000 yen difference in the fares.  However, we had about 45 min to sort this all out, if I had been in a hurry I would have tried just doing a fare adjustment (乗り越し *norikoshi*) on board or on arrival at Tokyo.

*Note: I'm accepting my own answer for now, but will happily bounty an answer that can go into more detail on the options here.*